# How to check the csv column name with mysql colomn when importing to mysql database in php

Tags: php

I am a importing a csv file to my database. The csv file have more than 30 columns. The problem is that sometimes the client changes the index of the columns in the csv files. Means the if for Ex. Name is in the first place and Address is in the Second place of the csv file then the some times it happens that Name is in the Second Place and Address is in the First place. In the present scenario i have to check manually all the fields of the csv and i have to do this for many other csv files and it becomes very difficult to do that. So is there a way that i can check the csv columns in php and insert them to the mysql database automatically at the desired column. This is the preset way i import data to the database by index numbers. The code is as:

```
while ($data = fgetcsv ($handle, 1000, ","))
{
if($dropdown1_value=="Canon")
    {
      $query="INSERT INTO `Import_CopiersandPrinters_Canon_Raw_Data` set `Account Name`  
              = '".htmlspecialchars($data[0],ENT_QUOTES)."', 
                 `Account Number` = '".htmlspecialchars($data[1],ENT_QUOTES)."',`Does 
                  Business As (DBA)` = '".htmlspecialchars($data[2],ENT_QUOTES)."',
                 `Shipping City` = '".htmlspecialchars($data[5],ENT_QUOTES)."', `Shipping 
                  Zip Postal Code` = '".htmlspecialchars($data[6],ENT_QUOTES)."',
                  `Phone` = '".htmlspecialchars($data[7],ENT_QUOTES)."',
                  `Lease Term` = '".str_replace(")","",str_replace(" 
                   (","-",str_replace(",","",str_replace("$","",$data[15]))))."', 
                   `Lease Expiration Date` = '".htmlspecialchars($data[17],ENT_QUOTES)."',
                   `file_name` = '".$new_file_name."', `file_date` = '".date('Y-m-d   
                    H:i:s')."'";

                   mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

                  if (mysql_error() <> "")
                  {             
                     fputcsv($output, $data);
                     $error_count++;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     $row_count = $row_count + 1;
                  }
                $total = $total+1;
             }
       }
```

Comment: How do you know the columns? Is it defined in the first rule of the CSV file? If true, are the column names in the CSV the same as the column names in your table?

Comment: @S.Pols Yes the column names are defined in the first rule of the CSV file and the column names in table and the column names in the csv file are same.

Comment: @S.Pols I have done some some work on this and now i am able to get the column names of the mysql table and the csv column names and i am not getting what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have 2 approuches. To write your query manual, or use the `implode` function. I made both examples for you. Let me know if you don't understand the code, or an error occurs. I think this will work. Note that you also should add your `if($dropdown1_value=="Canon")` check.

The manual approuch:

```
$columnArray    = array();
$dataArray      = array();
$firstRule      = true;

while ($data = fgetcsv ($handle, 1000, ","))
{
    if($firstRule)
    {
        foreach($data as $columnName)
        {
            $columnArray[] = $columnName;
        }

        $firstRule = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $rule = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < count($data) ; $i++)
        {
            $rule[$columnArray[$i]] = $data[$i];
        }
        $dataArray[] = $rule;
    }
}

foreach($dataArray as $data)
{
    $query="INSERT INTO `Import_CopiersandPrinters_Canon_Raw_Data` set `Account Name`  
          = '".htmlspecialchars($data['Account Name'],ENT_QUOTES)."', 
            `Account Number` = '".htmlspecialchars($data[1],ENT_QUOTES)."',
            `Does Business As (DBA)` = '".htmlspecialchars($data['Does Business As (DBA)'],ENT_QUOTES)."',
            `Shipping City` = '".htmlspecialchars($data['Shipping City'],ENT_QUOTES)."',
            ....
            ....
            ....
            `file_name` = '".$new_file_name."', 
            `file_date` = '".date('Y-m-d  H:i:s')."'";

    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    //Note that this would't reach when an error occured, because you used `or die`. You should use `or print` when you want to continue your code
    if (mysql_error() <> "")
    {             
        fputcsv($output, $data);
        $error_count++;
    }
    else
    {
        $row_count = $row_count + 1;
    }

    $total = $total+1;
}
```

The `implode` approuch:

```
function convert($string)
{
    return htmlspecialchars($string,ENT_QUOTES);
}

$columnArray    = array();
$dataArray      = array();
$firstRule      = true;

while ($data = fgetcsv ($handle, 1000, ","))
{
    if($firstRule)
    {
        foreach($data as $columnName)
        {
            $columnArray[] = $columnName;
        }

        $firstRule = false;
    }
    else
    {
        $rule = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < count($data) ; $i++)
        {
            $rule[$columnArray[$i]] = $data[$i];
        }
        $dataArray[] = $rule;
    }
}

foreach($dataArray as $data)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO `Import_CopiersandPrinters_Canon_Raw_Data` (`".implode('`,`', array_keys($data))."`, `file_name`, `file_date`) VALUES('".implode('\',\'', array_map("convert",array_values($data)))."', '".$new_file_name."', '".date('Y-m-d  H:i:s')."')";

    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    //Note that this would't reach when an error occured, because you used `or die`. You should use `or print` when you want to continue your code
    if (mysql_error() <> "")
    {             
        fputcsv($output, $data);
        $error_count++;
    }
    else
    {
        $row_count = $row_count + 1;
    }

    $total = $total+1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I am implementing it but the data is not getting inserted into the database. May be i am making some mistake. I am implementing it and i will let you know.

Comment: Which approuch did you use?

Comment: Add a `echo $query;` before `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` and give me the output please. I think there is something wrong with your query.